# Unconfirmed transaction, fees paid, seem to be two payments

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Transaction id: 601536cadb0055cee97b4ff7969c707bea18745168fe6fedae95f854b2168b11

I made this transaction several hours ago. It seems like it is stuck at being unconfirmed even though I paid a transaction fee of 0.000129 BTC.

I can see the transaction details at: https://blockchain.info/tx/601536cadb0055cee97b4ff7969c707bea18745168fe6fedae95f854b2168b11

I don't understand why there are two payments. Really confused as to what is going on and what the outcome will be. Will this transaction ever get confirmed? Will it eventually time out if it doesn't enter the blockchain and the BTC transfer back to the originating wallet?

Really appreciate any help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) confirmed

2) change

I do not know what else to say. Why don't you read the basic docs before using this technology?